# Unity suddenly won't build WebGL version on one specific project

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, unity-webgl

so my unity (2017.3.1f) suddenly won't build my project to webGL.

it did before and i simply made an update to a function which formats numbers into a string and then tried to build the update. built to standalone desktop with no problem, built to android absolutely fine but when i try to build to webGL it gives me the following errors (at end of post)

I've tried building a empty scene on another project and built with no issues. I've also tried to import one of the scenes into another new project (which builds fine before the import) but not after.

Anyone know what is going on here??

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i just don't understand what the error is saying. I've googled as much as i could in regards to this error and the files mentioned (python.exe, emcc_arguments.resp, build.bc) but none of these solutions has worked so far.

thanks,

> Failed running "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe"
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc"
>   @"C:\Users\Zaine\Desktop\Projects\Ember\Assets..\Temp\emcc_arguments.resp"
>
> stdout:
>   stderr:WARNING:root:C:\Users\Zaine\Desktop\Projects\Ember\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native\build.bc
>   is not valid LLVM bitcode ERROR:root:no input files note that input
>   files without a known suffix are ignored, make sure your input files
>   end with one of: ('.c', '.C', '.i', '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c++',
>   '.CPP', '.CXX', '.CC', '.C++', '.ii', '.m', '.mi', '.mm', '.mii',
>   '/dev/null', '.bc', '.o', '.obj', '.lo', '.dylib', '.so', '.a', '.ll',
>   '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh', '.H', '.HXX', '.HPP', '.HH')
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> Exception: Failed building WebGL Player.
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.ProgramUtils.StartProgramChecked
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/ProgramUtils.cs:48)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.EmscriptenLink
>   (BuildPostProcessArgs args, Boolean wasmBuild, System.String
>   sourceFiles, System.String sourceFilesHash) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:408)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.LinkBuild
>   (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:451)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:916)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup
>   targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath,
>   System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width,
>   Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
>   usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:272)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> Error building Player: 3 errors
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UPDATE: when I switch from webGL to another platform (standalone desktop) and then switch back to webGL and then try again to build, i get a slightly different error.

> Failed running "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe"
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc"
>   @"C:\Users\Zaine\Desktop\TestBuilding\Ember\Assets..\Temp\emcc_arguments.resp"
>
> stdout: stderr:WARNING:root:--separate-asm works best when compiling
>   to HTML. otherwise, you must yourself load the '.asm.js' file that is
>   emitted separately, and must do so before loading the main '.js` file
>   wrote symbol map file to
>   C:\Users\Zaine\Desktop\TestBuilding\Ember\Temp\StagingArea\Data\linkresult_asm\build.js.symbols
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc",
>   line 13, in 
>       emcc.run()   File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py",
>   line 1972, in run
>       JSOptimizer.flush()   File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py",
>   line 1868, in flush
>       run_passes(chunks[0], title, just_split=False, just_concat=False)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py",
>   line 1841, in run_passes
>       final = shared.Building.js_optimizer(final, passes, debug_level >= 4, JSOptimizer.extra_info, just_split=just_split,
>   just_concat=just_concat)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\shared.py",
>   line 1828, in js_optimizer
>       ret = js_optimizer.run(filename, passes, NODE_JS, debug, extra_info, just_split, just_concat)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\js_optimizer.py",
>   line 559, in run
>       return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: run_on_js(filename, passes, js_engine, source_map, extra_info, just_split, just_concat))
>   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\tempfiles.py",
>   line 78, in run_and_clean
>       return func()   File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\js_optimizer.py",
>   line 559, in 
>       return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: run_on_js(filename, passes, js_engine, source_map, extra_info, just_split, just_concat))
>   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\js_optimizer.py",
>   line 451, in run_on_js
>       filenames = pool.map(run_on_chunk, commands, chunksize=1)   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 250, in map
>       return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
>   line 554, in get
>       raise self._value AssertionError: Error in optimizer (return code -1073740791):  UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your Player Settings.

Comment: @bolkay the player settings have not changed since the last time i successfully built. I've tried switching a few settings around but still no luck